# rel="noopener noreferrer" is not being added after added the safe_target_blank gem, nor when I try to do it manually

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am fixing this vulnerability in my Ruby on Rails app and am having trouble getting it working. I tried changing this line in one of my .html.erb files:

```
<%= link_to account.Website, account.Website, :target => "_blank" %>
```

to:

```
<%= link_to account.Website, account.Website, :target => "_blank", :rel => "noopener noreferrer" %>
```

But when I load that page it has no `rel` in the `href`. I then found the safe_target_blank gem which is supposed to handle this automatically for you whenever the `target="_blank"` but it, too, is not producing any `rel` values in the `href`.

The output I am getting (where test account.Website is http://www.google.com/):

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com/">http://www.google.com/</a>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what `account.Website` please add `routes.rb`

Comment: account.Website is just a salesforce account website field. In this case the value is just http://www.google.com/ as a test.

Comment: I say you should put a pry in the gems code and see where things are being lost.

Comment: Can you try `<%= link_to account.Website, account.Website, { :target => "_blank" }, { :rel => "noopener noreferrer" } %>`?
According to the source https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to, link_to accepts two hash option arguments. I think the second one is the one which will add html atributes to the tag. Maybe it will not "compile", but give this a shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by using a "rel" string instead of the :rel symbol:

`<%= link_to account.Website, account.Website, :target => "_blank", "rel" => "noopener noreferrer" %>`